# ASP.NET Self-Referencing Relationship with Many-to-Many separate table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a contact model that I want to self reference. Each contact can have many relationships. For example let's say I have 3 contacts, John, Jake, and ABC Company. John and Jake are both employees of ABC Company so it would have 2 relationships.

I also want to apply a relationship "type" to each relationship. I want to store these types in a separate table that I can access to assign a type to each relationship created. So ABC Company would show "Jake; Employee" and "John; CEO". I could even add a third relationship like "John; Founder".

The navigation properties in my models are incorrect, plus I think I may need to use the Fluent API, but not sure how.

When updating the database I get this error.

```
Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Contact.Relationships' of type 'ICollection<Relationship>'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
```

Here are my models.

```
 public class Contact
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? FirstName { get; set; }

        public string? LastName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Relationship> Relationships { get; set; } = new HashSet<Relationship>();
    }
```

```
public class Relationship
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }


        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Contact? Parent { get; set; }

        public int ChildId { get; set; }
        public virtual Contact? Child { get; set; }



        public virtual RelationshipType? relationshipType { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class RelationshipType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Type { get; set; }


        public int? RelationshipId { get; set; }
        public virtual Relationship? relationship { get; set; }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the main issue is that EF Core cannot determine the foreign key relationships between the entities automatically based on the navigation properties. So we need to use the Fluent API to explicitly configure the relationships.

here is setup :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>(b =>
{
    b.HasMany(c => c.Relationships)
        .WithOne(r => r.Parent)
        .HasForeignKey(r => r.ParentId);
});

// Relationship configuration  
modelBuilder.Entity<Relationship>(b =>
{
    b.HasOne(r => r.Parent)
        .WithMany(c => c.Relationships)
        .HasForeignKey(r => r.ParentId);

    b.HasOne(r => r.Child)
        .WithMany() 
        .HasForeignKey(r => r.ChildId);

    b.HasOne(r => r.RelationshipType)
        .WithOne(rt => rt.Relationship)
        .HasForeignKey<RelationshipType>(rt => rt.RelationshipId);
});
```